# log4j : how to specify Specify default MDC value?

Tags: java, log4j

I have a java program with multiple "modules" each having its own set of thread. I would like to be able to grep logs from specific modules so i would like to have each module log starting with "[moduleId]".

I have tried using log4j with the following configurtion:

```
log4j.rootLogger=i, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%X{moduleId}] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L %t - %m%n
```

and using

```
MDC.put("moduleId", "module1");
```

In each module thread.

This works fine but i have code responsible of managing modules where it is hard for me to use MDC.put() and those threads logs starts with
[] because MDC variable "moduleId" isn't defined.

Is it possible with log4j (or with an other java logger) to specify a default value for "moduleId" variable ?

So that the code

```
logger.info("1");
MDC.put("moduleId", "module1");
logger.info("2");
```

Logs

```
[system] ... 1
[module1] ... 2
```

instead of

```
[] ... 1
[module1] ... 2
```

Also is there a way that multiline logs (for example stacktraces) have all their lines starting with [moduleId] instead of just the first line?